# How to read data from COM port with C language

Tags: c, windows, winapi, serial-port, readfile

I have been coding on C/C++ for a while but now I have faced a major problem which I can not resolve. I am trying to communicate with COM port. First I am sending data with WriteFile(), this part works.But when it comes to receiving an answer from the port with ReadFile(), I do not get anything.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int n=0;
   DCB dcb={0};
   HANDLE hCom;
   BOOL fSuccess;
   char *pcCommPort = "COM3";
   DWORD dwBytesRead=0;
   DWORD dwRead;
   DWORD dwBytesWrite=0;
   DWORD dwWrite=0;
/***************************************CommTimeouts******************************************/
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts={0};
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=200;
//timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=1;
//timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=1;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=2;
//timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=1;
/*******************************************Handle*******************************************/
   hCom = CreateFile( pcCommPort,
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ,    // must be opened with exclusive-access
                    NULL, // no security attributes
                    OPEN_EXISTING, // must use OPEN_EXISTING
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,    // not overlapped I/O
                    NULL  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
                    );
/***************************************SET*UP*COM*PORT**************************************/
   if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
       printf ("CreateFile failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());
       CloseHandle(hCom);
       return (1);
   }

   if(!SetCommTimeouts(hCom, &timeouts))
    {
        /*Well, then an error occurred*/
   }

   fSuccess = GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

   if (!fSuccess)
   {

     /*More Error Handling*/
      printf ("GetCommState failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());
      CloseHandle(hCom);

      return (2);
   }
   dcb.BaudRate = 9600;     // set the baud rate
   dcb.ByteSize = 8;             // data size, xmit, and rcv
   dcb.Parity = EVENPARITY;        // no parity bit
   dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    // one stop bit
   fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

   if (!fSuccess)
   {
      printf ("SetCommState failed. Error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
      CloseHandle(hCom);
      return (3);
   }

   printf ("Serial port %s successfully configured.\n", pcCommPort);
 //  return (0);
/*************************************Writing************************************************/
char bytes_to_send[] = {'36'};
if(!WriteFile(hCom, bytes_to_send, 2, &dwBytesWrite, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        CloseHandle(hCom);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("dwBytesWrite = %d | %x\n", dwBytesWrite, (dwBytesWrite));
/*************************************Reading************************************************/

char bytes_to_receive[7];

if(!ReadFile(hCom, bytes_to_receive, 7, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
      printf ("SetCommState failed. Error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
      CloseHandle(hCom);
      return (4);
} else {
printf("Bytes read %d -> %d\n",dwBytesRead, bytes_to_receive);}


/********************************************************************************************/

CloseHandle(hCom);

return(0);

}
```

Comment: `char bytes_to_send[] = {'36'};` --> `char bytes_to_send[] = {'3','6'};` and you write only 2 bytes but you try to read 7 bytes.

Comment: The problem is not in the WriteFile(), it is in ReadFile().

Comment: Are you certain your problem is in read? Have you tried using a terminal emulator to view the com port data? Read serial did have issues back in the days of DOS/win32, because you had to read it at exactly the same frequency in bytes that you had set it to receive in bits, which should not be relevant on any other platform.

Comment: Uhh... how to check if this is the problem?

Comment: Try using a terminal emulator to view the output on a second machine?

Comment: The second machine is weighing machine. 
When I pass `bytes_to_send[] = {'35' }` it should clear the scale and it is clearing it, but when I pass `bytes_to_send[] = {'36' }` it should send me back 1 start bit 1 end bit and 8 data bits.

Comment: What they are trying to tell you is that `'36'` is fishy, as `char` doesn't come with multiple character literals in Windows (or anywhere else, use `wchar_t` for that). You should either use `{'3', '6'}`/ `"36"` or `{'$'}` depending on if you want to send "36" or "$". Don't write ASCII codes with decimal numbers in source code.

Comment: I change it to `{'3', '6'}` but it does not make any difference.

Comment: and which error return `ReadFile` ? also here more relable will be call `NtReadFile` and check it status - possible `STATUS_TIMEOUT` for example, which is lost in call `ReadFile`

Comment: Actually `ReadFile()` is not returning error. The program just not receive anything.
It should get an 9 bytes of information. I will try `NtReadFile`.

Comment: call [`NtReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devnotes/ntreadfile) in place `ReadFile` - i guess `STATUS_TIMEOUT` error

Comment: Actually... you probably just need to call ReadFile from a loop until it reads something. CreateFile should clear the UART buffer so sending something to the port before CreateFile does little good. And there's no chance of sending anything between CreateFile and ReadFile calls because it goes way too fast.

Comment: I add `while(!dwBytesRead){
        if(!ReadFile(hCom, bytes_to_receive, 10, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
          printf ("SetCommState failed. Error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
          CloseHandle(hCom);
          return (4);
        } else {
        printf("Bytes read %d\n",dwBytesRead);
    }` Is that what you mean, because if it is it get stuck in infinity cycle.

Comment: Whit what params should I call function `NtReadFile()`?
`NtReadFile(hCom, EVENT, ApcRoutine, ApcContext, IoStatusBlock, bytes_to_recive, 9, ByteOffset, Key)`
what values I should asign to `EVENT, ApcRoutine, ApcContext, IoStatusBlock, Key`.

Comment: `IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
   NtReadFile(hCom, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, bytes_to_receive, sizeof(bytes_to_receive), 0, 0);`

Comment: `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` is giving me unknown type name.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block - define it itself, if you not include ntifs.h

Comment: Do you mean `#include <ntdef.h>`?

Comment: no, i mean exactly ntifs.h or wdm.h how minimum, but if you not do this before - more easy for you copy paste some definitions for `NtReadFile` or under debugger trace your `ReadFile` and look what is `NtReadFile` return how minimum for begin

Comment: I get `undefined reference to "NtReadFile"` but I am sure that everything is defined.

Comment: because you need add `ntdll.lib` to linker input. or via `GetProcAddress`

Comment: Am I supposed to use `NtCreateFile` and `NtWriteFile`?

Comment: no any different are you open file via `CreateFile` or `NtOpenFile` or `NtCreateFile`. sense in call `NtReadFile` instead `ReadFile` because last api lost `STATUS_TIMEOUT` which is possible with com port

Answer (score 0):

There is a file pointer, both for read and write. After the WriteFile it is at the end of the file. If you try to read from it, you will read at the end of the file. To read what you just wrote you have to reposition the file pointer at the start of the file, using the `SetFilePointer` function:

```
SetFilePointer(hCom, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
```